# How to set "Your name"

Tags: android-instant-apps

I cannot find any documentation or examples so I'm looking for guidance. When my Instant app is downloaded it shows up in Settings>Google>Google Play Instant with the app name and below that "Your Name". Other apps have found how to set "Your Name", for example, The NYTimes - Crossword has "The New York Times Company".

Is there a variable in a Manifest or a gradle file that needs to be filled?

Answer (score 2):

I found out from Google Developer Support that the problem occurs if Instant Apps Dev Manager is installed and/or when the app is sideloaded.

The fix was to Uninstall IA Dev Manager, Clear App Data for my Instant App then re-execute the download from the Play Store. Checking Settings>Google>Google Play Instant the Instant App appears and the company name from my listing of the app with the Play Store shows up underneath. There is no Manifest or gradle attribute to supply; it comes from the Play Store automatically - if it's not blocked.